# Changing frame outer color when clicked in it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Iam using the frame to get rounded corners for entry in android,i gave outlinecolor for frame,but i would like to know is there any possibility for changing the outline color of frame when entry is filling.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="20" Padding="0,0,0,0" HasShadow="False" OutlineColor="DarkMagenta" >
                <Entry Placeholder="Enter Name" Text="{Binding UserName}"  FontSize="10"/>
            </Frame>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add focus event to the frame.

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" CornerRadius="20"  Padding="10,10,10,10" HasShadow="False" OutlineColor="DarkMagenta"  Focused="frame_Focused">
```

Code behind:

```
private void frame_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    frame.OutlineColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it using a behaivor to change the outline color of the frame. here is a sample https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/. If you don't want to use behaivor you have to change the color in some entry handler like TextChanged,Focused,UnFocused.....

Comment: I have tried text changed event by giving name to frame but the outline color is not changing.